# htaccess url rewrite for wordpress (wp-admin)

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the wp-admin folder and somehow its working. but when i click on any of the link inside wp-admin its giving 403.
I have the following structure : http://domainname.com/dynamic_folder/wp-admin/

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /wp-admin/

RewriteRule ^(.*)/wp-admin/(.*)   $1/dashboard/$2   [R,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/dashboard(.*)$  $1/wp-admin$2
```

This is what i get when clicking any link inside wp-admin:
[image: image1]

Comment: are you trying to rename /wp-admin to /dashboard?

Comment: yes correct, and good thing is that the following works as main site:
http://domain.com/wp-admin without any problem. All links are perfectly working

 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /wp-admin/
 RewriteRule ^wp-admin/(.*)$ backpanel/$1 [R,L]
 RewriteRule ^backpanel(.*)$ wp-admin$1